# Null reference exception in Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, c#-4.0

I am .net beginner. I have gone through many sites before asking here. I am getting error -- "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  .This error comes usually when there are null values in any control but in my case Every control has some text in them, then why this error coming?  here is my [xml file](http://ideone.com/OnpgJ)

```
cmbProduct        --> combobox 
txtNewBrand       --> textBox
txtUpdateQuantity --> textBox
txtUpdatePrice    --> textBox
```

I tried the below code:

**onButtonClick**

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"..\..\stock.xml");
var newElement = new XElement("items",
                               new XElement("productname", cmbProduct.Text),
                               new XElement("brandname", txtNewBrand.Text),
                               new XElement("quantity", txtUpdateQuantity.Text),
                               new XElement("price", txtUpdatePrice.Text));
 /*ERROR*/      doc.Element("stock").Add(newElement);
                doc.Save(xpath);
                MessageBox.Show("updated successfully");
```

EDIT :

*Instead of using*

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"..\..\stock.xml");
```

i used

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\stock.xml");
```

and the problem solved. why so?

Comment: Check the that doc.Element("stock") actually has a value and is not returning null.

Comment: ok i will check whether the doc is null or not thankyou. I will intimidate you wait

Comment: I think the doc is not null. I edited my question

Comment: Almost all cases of NullReferenceException are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the exception because:

```
doc.Element("stock").Add(newElement);
```

`stock` is the root node, and `doc.Element("stock")` returns null. What you are actually trying to do is to add an item in your xml. Try the following:

```
doc.Add(newElement);
```

This will give you the desired result.

Comment: I wasn't aware that root node has different functionaliy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

eather doc.Element("stock") can't be found and is NULL or doc is NULL

Answer (score 1):

Given the limited code it isn't easy to see what you have added and/or asserted to exist.  Try adding these two lines above your error and the error message will indicate the fault.

```
Debug.Assert(doc != null, "Can not operate without a valid instance of 'doc'");
Debug.Assert(doc.Element("stock") != null, "Need the stock element to add to!");
```

You may need to include "using System.Diagnostics;" at the top of the file.

Comment: it is showing these diagnostics.. which i cant understand http://i47.tinypic.com/25u1enn.jpg

Comment: The first line is "need stock element to add to" - which is the 2nd line of the code I said to insert.  Therefore, you need to add a "stock" to doc. e.g. `var stock = doc.Add(new Element("stock"));` and change your line to `stock.Add(newElement)`

Comment: well just for checkin i added `var doc = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\stock.xml");` this worked. why i cant understand. this code `XElement doc = XElement.Load(@"..\..\stock.xml");` became useless here?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you didn't pre-load the `doc` with an existing XML, if so there won't be any `stock` element to start with.

Try adding this

```cs
if (doc.Element("stock") == null)
{
    doc.Add(new XElement("stock"));
}
```

before

```
doc.Element("stock").Add(newElement);
```